# undefined reference to `FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

---

Hi everyone,
 when i trying to execute and compiler my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159
void MainMenu();
double MenuToChoose(double R,double r,double volume,double area,int choice);
double FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea(double R,double r);
double Compute(double R,double r,double volume,double density,int choice1,double mass,double L1,double S1,double C1,double B1,double N1,double I1,double A1);
int main(){
    int choice;
    double R,r,volume,area;
    do{
    MainMenu();
    MenuToChoose(R,r,area,volume,choice);   
    }
    while (choice != 3);
}
void MainMenu(){
    int choice;
    double R,r;
    double area,volume;
    printf("\n-------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n1-    Volume and Surface area of the sphare");
    printf("\n2-    Mass of the sphare");
    printf("\n3-    Exit");
        printf("\n\n    Please Enter your Choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("\nYour choice is: %d",choice);
        if(choice == 1){
    printf("\nYour have chosen to find Volume and Surface area: ");
    printf("\nEnter Radii of the sphere: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf",&R,&r);
    FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea(R,r);
}
    if(choice == 2){
    MenuToChoose(R,r,area,volume,choice);
    }
        if(choice == 3){
    printf("Your choice (3) to Exit.");
        printf("\nThanks for using my program !");  
        return ;
    }
double MenuToChoose(double R,double r,double area,double volume,int choice){
    char choice1,L,l,S,s,C,c,B,b,N,n,I,i,A,a;
    double mass,L1,S1,C1,B1,N1,I1,A1,density;
    printf("\nYour have chosen to find Mass of object: ");
    printf("\nEnter Radii of the sphere: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf",&R,&r); 

    printf("\nSolids   Density      (g/cm3)");
    printf("\n--------------------------------");
    printf("\nL        Lead          11.37");
    printf("\nS        Silver            10.57");
    printf("\nC        Copper            8.92");
    printf("\nB        Brass             8.90");
    printf("\nN        Nickel            8.57");
    printf("\nI        Iron          7.90");
    printf("\nA        Aluminium         2.67");
    density = L1 = 11.37; 
    density = S1 = 10.57; 
    density = C1 = 8.92; 
    density = B1 = 8.90; 
    density = N1 = 8.57; 
    density = I1 = 7.90; 
    density = A1 = 2.67; 
    printf("\n  Enter choice: ");
    scanf(" %c",&choice1);  
    Compute(R,  r,  volume,  density,choice1,  mass,  L1,  S1,  C1,  B1,  N1,  I1,  A1);
return density;
return choice1;
return L1;
return S1;
return C1;
return B1;
return N1;
return I1;
return A1;
}
double FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea(double R,double r){
    double area,volume;
    area = 3 * PI * pow(r,2) + PI * (pow(R,2));
    volume = ((4/3.0) * PI * (pow(r,3) - pow(R,3) ))/2;
    printf("\n\nVolume = %.2lf  Area = %.2lf",volume,area);
    MainMenu();
}
double Compute(double R,double r,double volume,double density,int choice1,double mass,double L1,double S1,double C1,double B1,double N1,double I1,double A1){
    printf("\nEnter Radii of the sphere: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf",&R,&r); 
    /********************************************************/
    if(choice1 == 'L' || choice1 == 'l'){
    mass = volume * L1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 
        else if(choice1 == 'S' || choice1 == 's'){
    mass = volume * S1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 
        else if(choice1 == 'C' || choice1 == 'c'){
    mass = volume * C1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 
        else if(choice1 == 'B' || choice1 == 'b'){
    mass = volume * B1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 
        if(choice1 == 'N' || choice1 == 'n'){
    mass = volume * N1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 
        else if(choice1 == 'I' || choice1 == 'i'){
    volume = ((4/3.0) * PI * (pow(r,3) - pow(R,3) ))/2;
    mass = volume * I1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 
        else if(choice1 == 'A' || choice1 == 'a'){
    mass = volume * A1;
    printf("\nSemi Sphare mass = %.2lf\n\n",mass);} 

    /*******************************************************/

}
}
//void Check(R,r){
//  int temp;
//  if (R > r)
//         {
//            temp = R;
//            R = r;
//            r = temp;
//         }
//}
//
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
main.c: In function ‘MainMenu’:
main.c:26:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  ^
main.c:31:2: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  scanf("%lf %lf",&R,&r);
  ^
/tmp/ccP8hsTP.o: In function `MainMenu':
main.c:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea'
main.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `MenuToChoose'
/tmp/ccP8hsTP.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup+0x22): undefined reference to `MenuToChoose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What on hell is going on?! i try to solve it many time but i cant
Thanks,
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Comment: Lots of problems here - A function can execute only one `return` statement;`MainMenu` and `FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea` keep calling each other; the `FindTheVolumeAndSurfaceArea` function doesn't return anything although the signature says it returns a `double` and so on... Start with a good book on C.

Comment: 'while (choice != 3);' - var accessed while undefined.  Then the massive number of other errors.   You should not let your code get to this stage!   Write main() and nearly-empty functions that return dummy values.  Test/debug.  Don't add more until lthat compiles and tests out. This source has so many syntax, logical, scoping and other errors that it's not sensibly possible to fix in an SO Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace `}` at the end of `MainMenu`.  That's why you're getting the "undefined reference" errors.  There's also an extra `}` at the end of the file.  Basically all of the functions after `MainMenu` are nested within `MainMenu`.